# SwiftUI Calling functions from other class

Tags: swift, function, swiftui

I am having a little trouble here: I have a class

```
class TempC {
    func GetData(){
          //do stuff
    }
}
```

And in ContentView I want to call the function, but I can't manage to do it, I am getting errors...

```
struct ContentView: View {

var variable : TempC
variable.GetData()
var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Or in any other method. How can I call an external function now?

PS: The error that I get are on the line with `variable.GetData()` which are:

> 1. Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ";"
> 2. Expected "("in argument list of cantons declaration
> 3. Expected "{"in body of function declaration
> 4. Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration
> 5. Invalid redeclaration of 'variable()'

It's like it is expecting to create a new function not to get the one that is already existing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Depending on what your going to do in that call there are options, ex:

**Option 1**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let variable = TempC()
    init() {
        variable.GetData()
    }
    var body: some View {
            Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let variable = TempC()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
        .onAppear {
            self.variable.GetData()
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly you can call it in .onTapGesture or any other, pass reference to your class instance during initialising, etc.

Comment: Good response! Was used with the UIKIT style of calling functions and methods, here I see I need to make an action or something.

Comment: What if variable.GetData() return a tuple then how to access it in var body: some View